# Implementing Hashtags in recyclerview in Android using AutoLinkTextView

Tags: java, android, hashtag, autolink

I'm currently developing the feature adding hashtags to my app, but I got stuck in implementing it in a recyclerview. I'm currently using the [AutoLinkTextView](https://github.com/armcha/AutoLinkTextView) I don't get the matched words for the textview I assigned as autolinktextview. Thanks for the help!

Holder Class

```
public class NewsfeedHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   private AutoLinkTextView txtContent;
   private String linkText


   public NewsHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       txtContent = (AutoLinkTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
}

public void setData(Activity activity, News news, OnNewsClickListener onNewsClickListener) {

    txtContent.setAutoLinkOnClickListener(new AutoLinkOnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAutoLinkTextClick(AutoLinkMode autoLinkMode, String matchedText) {
            linkText = matchedText;


public void setLinkListener(final AutoLinkOnClickListener autoLinkOnClickListener) {
    txtContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        AutoLinkMode autoLinkMode = AutoLinkMode.MODE_HASHTAG;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            autoLinkOnClickListener.onAutoLinkTextClick(autoLinkMode , linkText);
        }
    });
}
```

And in my Adapter onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_ITEM:
            News news = (News) arrayList.get(position);
            NewsHolder newsHolder = (NewsHolder) holder;
            newsHolder.setData(activity, news, onNewsClickListener);
            newsHolder.setListener(news, onNewsClickListener);
            newsHolder.setLinkListener(autoLinkOnClickListener);
            break;
    }

}
```

And in the Activity, I set the autoLinkOnClickListener using

```
adapter.setAutoLinkTextClick(this);
```

How can I implement this in my activity?

Comment: add your files, please

Comment: without code nobody can help you ..

Comment: see edited post